# Webpack config setup causing webpack-dev-server to throw a 404

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I am running

`webpack-dev-server`

it is not loading some of the resources

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Which is a `.jpg` image that I point out below.

My project will compile and display, it just will not show the images. But I noticed if I navigate to another path in the url instead of base index `http://localhost:3000/` , it then will throw the following

> GET http://localhost:3000/pages/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

**Project Directory**

```
|-- project
|-- webpack.config.js
|-- dist
|   |-- favicon.ico
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- main.js
|   |-- 398938.jpg <---throwing the failed to load resource
```

**webpack.config.js snippet**

```
 entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",

  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./dist/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      favicon: "./dist/favicon.ico"
    })
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/")` shouldn't actually be `contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/dist")`?

Comment: Tried this and the same error still occurs, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I was running into a similar issue just now, and using simply contentBase: './dist' ended up doing the trick for me